# Setting 'relaxedQueryChars' for embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

How can I set `relaxedQueryChars` for Spring Boot embedded Tomcat?

The connector attribute described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html), but Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) has no such parameter listed.

How to set Tomcat's Connector attributes in general?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do this with properties file. I believe this should work

```
@Component
public class MyTomcatWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector connector) {
                connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "yourvaluehere");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but might be simplified with lambda `factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "yourvaluehere"))`

Comment: may worth mentioning that connector.setAttribute was deprecated in 8, 9 and completely removed in 10
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Spring Boot 2.x then you need to use WebSeerverFactoryCustomizer as given below.

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> 
    containerCustomizer(){
    return new EmbeddedTomcatCustomizer();
}

private static class EmbeddedTomcatCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
            connector.setAttribute("relaxedPathChars", "<>[\\]^`{|}");
            connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "<>[\\]^`{|}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include @Configuration annotation for the class that contains this.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest method is to configure the server (add a line to application.properties).
You can add something like this:

```
server.tomcat.relaxed-path-chars=<,>,etc
```

- [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties-server) Comma-separated list of additional unencoded characters that should be allowed in URI paths. Only "< > [ \ ] ^ ` { | }" are allowed.*

Answer (score 5):

I did this as a working solution for me:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer(){
    return new MyCustomizer();
}

private static class MyCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) {
        if(factory instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            customizeTomcat((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory);
        }
    }

    void customizeTomcat(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
            connector.setAttribute("relaxedPathChars", "<>[\\]^`{|}");
            connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "<>[\\]^`{|}");
        });
    }

}
```